# .net event handlers using filesystemwatcher cleanup

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, filesystemwatcher

I've writte a simple test tool using the .net FileSystemWatcher class. The problem is I got a memory leak because instances of MemoryLeakTest are referenced by the changed handler in the FileSystemWatcher. What would be the correct way of cleaning up this reference so that the garbage collector could afterwards collect the MemoryLeakTest instance and the FileSystemWatcher instance?

To see the leaked instances on the heap follow this instructions:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2008/04/11/8381838.aspx

Thanks in advance for your advice

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace MemoryLeakTest {

class Leaking {

    private FileSystemEventHandler changedHandler;
    private FileSystemWatcher fsw;

    public Leaking() {
        changedHandler = new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Changed);

        fsw = new FileSystemWatcher("c:\\", "*.*");
        fsw.Changed += changedHandler;
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    ~Leaking() {
        fsw.Changed -= changedHandler;
        fsw.Dispose();                        
    }

    void fsw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Changed");
    }

}


class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            var x = new Leaking();
        }
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well for one you should be implementing IDisposable and doing your cleanup in .Dispose(), not in a finalizer.

Comment: Then I would have to call Dispose() for long living objects manually somewhere. I'd like to have this step automated so I don't forget to do so.

Comment: After some more research it seems like I have to implement IDisposable in every class that has a member that implements IDisposable. This seems to easily "pollute" my whole data model up to the root object. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should implement `IDisposable` in every class that has a member that implements `IDisposable`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=VS.100).aspx.

However, implementing `IDisposable` just makes sure that resources are cleaned up in a timely manner. Typically, failure to implement `IDisposable` won't result in a long-term memory leak because the garbage collector will eventually get around to running the finalizers, and those will release the operating system resources. But not disposing can cause short-term memory leaks and resource exhaustion. It *can* cause a long-term problem, but that's relatively uncommon when working with BCL objects.

For example, in your test program above, the `Leaking` objects that you create are "rootless" once you exit the loop, and as you saw the garbage collector does collect them. If you were to let your program run for a while, doing other things, those objects would be collected during the next garbage collection. It's a short-term memory and resource leak, but not a long-term problem.

Now, you *could* run into a memory leak if you have something like:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(...);
void MakeABigLeak()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        var MyObject = new SomeObject();
        watcher.Changed += MyObject.ChangeHandler;
    }
}
```

In this case, the `watcher` holds a reference to each of the created objects. And since `watcher` is rooted, those objects will remain active. They won't be garbage collected.

The only way to fix this is to ensure that the object removes itself from the event notification. You can do that in the object's `Dispose` method, although there are other ways, too. However, you have to be careful *not* to do that in the finalizer. Remember that finalizers run in no set order. It's possible that the `watcher` was finalized before the object that references it (since neither is rooted, finalization order doesn't matter). That's why the `Dispose(bool)` method exists: to prevent you from accessing other objects during finalization.

It's your choice. You can write a `Dispose` method that removes the object from the event notification, or you can be sure to write code that does the removal when the object is no longer interested in the event. The drawback to doing this in `Dispose` is that the object doing the subscribing has to maintain a reference to the object that's raising the events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a really complex topic. Currently I'm doing some research on event handler, weak references ...

Answer (score 2):

You may also be running into a memory leak in the FileWatcher itself.  See the following: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565720/memory-leak-in-system-io-filesystemwatcher

Comment: To see this link I must register. Can you please provide a summary here?